# Pass Dropdownlist selected values from controller to view MVC5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have dropdown list in view as following :

```
<td>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Priority, new SelectList(new List<object>{
                                                                                                     new { value="Select", text= "--Select--" },
                                                                                                    new { value="High", text= "High" },
                                                                                                    new { value ="Normal", text= "Normal" },
                                                                                                    new { value ="Low", text= "Low" }
                                                                                                     }, "value", "text", 0), new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Priority, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </td>
```

I have values for 'Priority' field in DB as 'Normal','Low','High'. I want to bind the selected value to bind in edit view. I pass data to edit view as following:

```
public ActionResult EditTaskDetails(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            List<Task_Detail> Tasks = new List<Task_Detail>();

            Task_Detail TaskDet = new Task_Detail();
            Tasks = new TaskDAO().GetTaskDetailById(id);

            ViewData["TaskDetails"] = Tasks;                      

            return View();
        }
```

In View, I bind other datas as following :

```
  @foreach (var task in ViewBag.TaskDetails)
                          {
     <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Task_Code, new { id = "txtTCode", Value = @task.Task_Code, @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_Code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Now, how can i bind this selected status value to bind in dropdown list from controller ?
Can anyone help me to do this..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum with those values:

```
public enum ValPriorities
{
High = 1,
Normal = 2,
Low = 3
}
```

Then create a selectlist object:

```
var selectList= new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ValPriorities)).Cast<ValPriorities>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = v.ToString(),
             Value = ((int)v).ToString()
         }).ToList(),"Value","Text");
```

Then in your controller:

```
ViewData["selectList"] = selectList;
```

or you could create it as model property and send it like:

```
return View(yourModel);
```

And in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, ViewData["selectList"],"--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my controller, i can get particular value for the selected record from Tasks[0].Task_status. How can i bind this value as selected value in view